# MismatchedInputException from ObjectMapper with no nested JSON

Tags: jackson, rabbitmq, objectmapper

I am receiving the following error when deserializing JSON into a Java object:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

I have the following JSON, which is stringified and sent as a RabbitMQ message:

```json
{"selection_id":1234};
```

Object to be deserialized into:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SelectionMessage implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("selection_id")
    Long selectionId;
}
```

And I read the JSON into an object using

```java
    @RabbitListener(
            id = "selectionHandler",
            queues = "#{'${my.selection.queue}'}")
    public void handleSelectionMessage(@Payload String payload) {
        try {
            SelectionMessage message =
                    objectMapper.readValue(payload, SelectionMessage.class);
            
            // ...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

I have seen this error for nested JSON objects, but this is happening with no nested JSON. It's as if the JSON string is no longer a String when it arrives at the object mapper. Does this mean I need to use a different message converter?